# c3js Multi color design

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js

I've implementing barchart to denote my result set. I am trying to create this design using c3js. I referred the documentation but have not getting the shaded design. Please someone guide me to solve this.

My Code Snippet is,

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  size : {
    width: 600,
    height: 200
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ["data1", 40, 20, 20, 20],
      ["data2", 20, 10, 30, 30]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
      ['data1', 'data2']
    ],
    order: null,
    labels: {
      format: function(v, id, i, j) {
        return v;
      }
    }
  },
  bar: {
    space: 0.2,
    width: {
      ratio: 0.2 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
    }
  },

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.3.0/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

[image]

My requirement is to design like below image in bars in barchart,

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Happy to try - please could you post a cut down working snippet of what you have so far ? I've put one in the answer below so you can cut & paste then modify as needed.

Comment: I edited your question to make your code actually run.

Comment: You can do that by creating patterns and assigning their id as colours. Just a tip - but you will be better helped if you ask one clear question and stick to it. I thought my answer was what you required but now I am not so sure. If my answer helped please mark it as correct. If not, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the snippet introduces some d3 SVG manipulation which puts a region over the bars of each targeted series. The region has a hatched grey line and a semi-transparent fill. The function to do this is written to be portable i.e. outside of the C3 construtor params, and is invoked by the onrendered c3 event.

The doClone() function duplicates nodes in place which is useful to know, and the creation of the pattern and use as a colour via 'url(#patternid)' is also a  potentially useful technique.

Also available at https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/yRWbvq

```js
function doClone(node){ // clone the given node
  return d3.select(node.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), node.nextSibling));  
 }

function hatchBars(hatchTargets){ // Place a hatching pattern over the target bars.

  for (var i = 0; i < hatchTargets.length; i = i + 1){

    d3.select('.c3-bars-' + hatchTargets[i]).each(function(d, i){
      d3.select(this).selectAll('path').each(function(d, i){

        var node = d3.select(this).node(); 
        var daClone = doClone(node); 
        
        daClone
          .style('fill', 'url(#hash4_4)') 
          .style('stroke', 'url(#hash4_4)');
          
      });
    })        
  }
  
}
c3.chart.internal.fn.afterInit = function () {

d3.select('defs')
  .append('pattern')
  .attr('id', "hash4_4") // use id to get handle in a moment
  .attr('width', 14)
  .attr('height', 14)
  .attr('patternUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr('patternTransform', "rotate(45 0 0 )")

  .append("rect")
  .attr('width', 14)
  .attr('height', 14)
  .attr('fill', '#00000000')  // transparent background
  
d3.select('#hash4_4')   // get the pattenn
  .append('line')  // add a line
  .attr('y2', 14)
  .style('stroke', "#00000044") // semi-transparent bars
  .attr('stroke-width', 14)  
};

//
// Standard C3 chart render with one twist which is the onrendered event call at the end.
//
var chart = c3.generate({
   bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    },
  
  onrendered: function () {  // execute after drawn
    
    hatchBars(['data2']); // Place a hatching pattern over the target bars.
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.js"></script>


<div class='chart-wrapper'>
<div class='chat' id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the bottom( combined ) colors which i attached in above screenshot. Or my requirement is to place some shade or variation to highlight bottom part alone.

Comment: Since you have not shared your data I cannot give you anything other than a specimen solution which must include assumptions. Always always post code - half the time you will solve your own problem as you slim down the issue to a simple repro.